# Using 100% height on div but respecting div content

Tags: html, css, height

I wasn't really too sure what to call this but I currently have a div for which I may not need percentage height for the '.right' class, but the issue is that with the specific individual list elements(as well as their respective divs) in the '.right' class, I would like to give percentage margin to them. Is there a possible work-around for this? Again, I just need to get margin in between each list element using percentages, not px. The snippet version's affected by the media query, but that's irrelevant with respect to the margins not working with percents. Can anybody help with this issue? I tried putting 100% height on '.container' but that throws everything out of whack.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    background-color: gray;
}
html, 
body {
  height: 100%;

}

.left {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    order: 1;
    width: 30%;
}
.middle {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    order: 2;
    width: 50%;
    height: 99%;
}
.scienceBox {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: gray;
 -radius: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 2%;
}
.scienceBox p {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 19px;
 background-color: green;
 padding: 0;
 color: white;
}
.scienceBox li {
 color: black;
 font-size: 17px;
 list-style-type: square;
}
.scienceBox special{
 list-style-type: circle;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    flex-wrap:  wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: stretch;
 padding-bottom: 2%;
    min-height: 70vh;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 5% auto 8% auto;
    background-color: white;
}
.container p { 
  margin-bottom: 12%; 
}
.container img {
  margin-bottom: 10%; 
}
.container img:first-child{ 
  margin-top: 5%;
}
.box1 {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 20px;
}
.box h2{ 
 color: orange;
 text-align: center;
}
.right {
 display: flex;
 position: relative;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 align-content: flex-start;
 justify-content: center;
 order: 3;
 width: 20%;

}
.right div{
 height: 25%;
}
.right .list{
    height: auto;
 text-align: center;
}
.list ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
.list a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}
.headbox h3{
    color: orange;
 text-align: center;
}

.sactive { /* s for sidebar */
 font-weight: bold;
}
a {
 color: orange;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.hundredw {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 10%;
 text-align: center;
}
.papajohns{
 position: absolute;
 top: 60%;
 right: 0;
 left: 0;
 margin: auto
}
.papajohns p {
 margin: 0 1%;
}
ul.square li {
 list-style-type: square;
 margin-bottom: 2%;
}
.mtop {
 margin-top: 3.5%;
}
@media all and (max-width: 900px) {
    #nav {
     flex-direction: column; /*updated*/
     margin-bottom: 7%;
    }
    #nav ul {
      padding-left: 0; /*added*/
    }
    #nav li {
      flex: 1 1 100%; /*updated*/
      padding: 5px;
      -top: 1px solid black;
      -bottom: 1px solid black;
    }   
    #nav li a{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    }
    #bigwrap {
      width: 100%;
    }
    .container {
      flex-flow: row wrap;
      min-height: 100vh;
      width: 100%;
    }
 .sarpinos{
  top:56%;
 }
 .left {
  align-content: flex-start;
  height: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
 }
 .middle {
  height: 40%;
 }
    .left, .right {
      flex: 1 100%;
    }
   .middle {
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    justify-content: center;
 align-content: flex-start;
   }
   .box {
    width: 70%;
    text-align: center;
   }
   #header2{
    justify-content: space-around;
   }
}

@media (min-width: 900px) and (max-width: 1100px) {
  
  #nav{
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
  .container {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" width="50" height="50" alt="Picture of void" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" width="50" height="50" alt="Picture of void" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" width="50" height="50" alt="Picture of void" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" width="50" height="50" alt="Picture of void" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" width="50" height="50" alt="Picture of void" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" width="50" height="50" alt="Picture of void" />


   <div class="hundredw">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" width="50" height="50" alt="Picture of void" />
               <div class="papajohns">
                    <p>file</p>
     <p>files</p>
     <p>files</p>
     <p><i>files</i></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="middle">
   <div class="box">
             <h2> Sample <h2>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
             <p>
               This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
                This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
                This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
                This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
                This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
                </p>
                <ul class="square">
              <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>         
      <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
      <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
    <ul>          
            </div>
            <div class="box mtop">
             <p>
                This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
                This is a sample sentence.This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
                This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
                This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
                This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="scienceBox">
       <p>This is a sample sentence.</p>
          <ul>
           <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
     <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
     <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
     <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
     <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
     <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
     <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
     <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
     <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
                    <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
                    <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
     <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
     <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
                    <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
                    <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
          </ul>
   </div>
            <div class="scienceBox">
       <p>This is a sample sentence.</p>
          <ul>
           <li>This is a sample sentence.?
                      <ul class="special">
                         <li>This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
                            This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
                            </li> 
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>This is a sample sentence.?
                     <ul class="special">
                         <li>This is a sample sentence.
                            </li> 
                        </ul>
                    </li>
     <li>Is This is a sample sentence.?
                     <ul class="special">
                         <li>This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
                            This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
                            </li> 
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <liThis is a sample sentence.?
                     <ul class="special">
                         <li>This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
                            This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
                            </li> 
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                            
   </div>
         </div>
         <div class="right">
          <div class="headbox">
             <h3>This is a sample sentence.</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="list">
                   <ul>
                       <li><a class="sactive" href="#">This is a sample sentence.</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">This is a sample sentence.</a></li>
                   </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="headbox">
             <h3>Important Informaiton</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="list2">
                   <ul>
                       <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
                       <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
                       <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
                       <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
                       <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
                   </ul>
                   <ul>
                       <li>Address</li>
                       <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
                       <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
                       <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
                   </ul>
                   <ul>
                       <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
                       <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
                       <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
                       <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
                   </ul>
                   
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: This question is not very clear.
First of all, try to trim your code, so that only the relevant parts are included here. Giving us all of your code makes it hard to pinpoint exactly which parts you're interested in help with.
Secondly, what is it exactly, you want to achieve? Perhaps give us an illustration of this?
You want the div.right element to have percentage height (as in height according to its parent) while it's children should have their vertical (top and bottom) margins in percentages related to div.right's height?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Thank you for responding. As it is now putting margin-bottom: 2% doesn't make anymore difference than margin-bottom: 4% on the '.right' class, they both do nothing even though '.container' is 100% height of body. Container has min-height and I'm facing this issue where If I were to make container 100% height, the height of my container does not contain all of my content, so it feels as if I am trapped. So in conclusion I need 'container' to hold all of the content in it and I need to be able to use percentage margins in the '.right' class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer your two problems seperately:

1) Why does your `.right` div not contain its contents?

You are doing two things here, that kind of contradict each other.
`.right` is set to adjust its height according to its contents height (height is defaulting to `auto`).
At the same time, the divs INSIDE `.right` are having their heights set according to `.right`'s height. This is circular.
In this way, first .right has its height calculated based on its contents, and THEN the contents heights are changed, making them move out of the boundaries of `.right`. 
Add this:

```
.right { height:100% }
```

2) How do I make the top- and bottom- margins adjust according to the parent height?

You can't do this with css.
Setting `.right { margin-top:5% }` will set `.right`'s `margin-top` according to the width of `.right`'s parents (yes, it's weird like that).
That is, `.right`'s `margin-top` would then be 5% of the `.container`'s width.

You can achieve this with Javascript.
Below I have copied your full code and added the jQuery code to do this, and also fixed the height/containment issue you had.

Otherwise, you can use `vh` and make the margins a certain percent of the viewport height, e.g.:

```
.right {
margin-bottom:4vh;
}
```

Would make it 4% of the Viewport Height.

```js
var containerHeight = $(".container").height();
$(".right").css("margin-bottom", containerHeight*0.15 );
$(".right").css("margin-top", containerHeight*0.05 );
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    background-color: gray;
}
html, 
body {
  height: 100%;

}

.left {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    order: 1;
    width: 30%;
}
.middle {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    order: 2;
    width: 50%;
    height: 99%;
}
.scienceBox {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: gray;
 -radius: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 2%;
}
.scienceBox p {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 19px;
 background-color: green;
 padding: 0;
 color: white;
}
.scienceBox li {
 color: black;
 font-size: 17px;
 list-style-type: square;
}
.scienceBox special{
 list-style-type: circle;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    flex-wrap:  wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: stretch;
 padding-bottom: 2%;
    min-height: 70vh;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 5% auto 8% auto;
    background-color: white;
}
.container p { 
  margin-bottom: 12%; 
}
.container img {
  margin-bottom: 10%; 
}
.container img:first-child{ 
  margin-top: 5%;
}
.box1 {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 20px;
}
.box h2{ 
 color: orange;
 text-align: center;
}
.right {
 display: flex;
 position: relative;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 align-content: flex-start;
 justify-content: center;
 order: 3;
 width: 20%;
 height:100%;

}
.right div{
 height: 25%;
}
.right .list{
    height: auto;
 text-align: center;
}
.list ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
.list a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}
.headbox h3{
    color: orange;
 text-align: center;
}

.sactive { /* s for sidebar */
 font-weight: bold;
}
a {
 color: orange;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.hundredw {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 10%;
 text-align: center;
}
.papajohns{
 position: absolute;
 top: 60%;
 right: 0;
 left: 0;
 margin: auto
}
.papajohns p {
 margin: 0 1%;
}
ul.square li {
 list-style-type: square;
 margin-bottom: 2%;
}
.mtop {
 margin-top: 3.5%;
}
@media all and (max-width: 900px) {
    #nav {
     flex-direction: column; /*updated*/
     margin-bottom: 7%;
    }
    #nav ul {
      padding-left: 0; /*added*/
    }
    #nav li {
      flex: 1 1 100%; /*updated*/
      padding: 5px;
      -top: 1px solid black;
      -bottom: 1px solid black;
    }   
    #nav li a{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    }
    #bigwrap {
      width: 100%;
    }
    .container {
      flex-flow: row wrap;
      min-height: 100vh;
      width: 100%;
    }
 .sarpinos{
  top:56%;
 }
 .left {
  align-content: flex-start;
  height: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
 }
 .middle {
  height: 40%;
 }
    .left, .right {
      flex: 1 100%;
    }
   .middle {
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    justify-content: center;
 align-content: flex-start;
   }
   .box {
    width: 70%;
    text-align: center;
   }
   #header2{
    justify-content: space-around;
   }
}

@media (min-width: 900px) and (max-width: 1100px) {
  
  #nav{
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
  .container {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" width="50" height="50" alt="Picture of void" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" width="50" height="50" alt="Picture of void" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" width="50" height="50" alt="Picture of void" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" width="50" height="50" alt="Picture of void" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" width="50" height="50" alt="Picture of void" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" width="50" height="50" alt="Picture of void" />


   <div class="hundredw">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" width="50" height="50" alt="Picture of void" />
               <div class="papajohns">
                    <p>file</p>
     <p>files</p>
     <p>files</p>
     <p><i>files</i></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="middle">
   <div class="box">
             <h2> Sample <h2>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
             <p>
               This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
                This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
                This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
                This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
                This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
                </p>
                <ul class="square">
              <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>         
      <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
      <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
    <ul>          
            </div>
            <div class="box mtop">
             <p>
                This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
                This is a sample sentence.This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
                This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
                This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
                This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="scienceBox">
       <p>This is a sample sentence.</p>
          <ul>
           <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
     <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
     <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
     <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
     <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
     <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
     <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
     <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
     <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
                    <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
                    <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
     <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
     <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
                    <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
                    <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
          </ul>
   </div>
            <div class="scienceBox">
       <p>This is a sample sentence.</p>
          <ul>
           <li>This is a sample sentence.?
                      <ul class="special">
                         <li>This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
                            This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
                            </li> 
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>This is a sample sentence.?
                     <ul class="special">
                         <li>This is a sample sentence.
                            </li> 
                        </ul>
                    </li>
     <li>Is This is a sample sentence.?
                     <ul class="special">
                         <li>This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
                            This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
                            </li> 
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <liThis is a sample sentence.?
                     <ul class="special">
                         <li>This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
                            This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
                            </li> 
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                            
   </div>
         </div>
         <div class="right">
          <div class="headbox">
             <h3>This is a sample sentence.</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="list">
                   <ul>
                       <li><a class="sactive" href="#">This is a sample sentence.</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">This is a sample sentence.</a></li>
                   </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="headbox">
             <h3>Important Informaiton</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="list2">
                   <ul>
                       <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
                       <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
                       <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
                       <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
                       <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
                   </ul>
                   <ul>
                       <li>Address</li>
                       <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
                       <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
                       <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
                   </ul>
                   <ul>
                       <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
                       <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
                       <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
                       <li>This is a sample sentence.</li>
                   </ul>
                   
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```